# Do I get any reputation from being upvoted/accepted on per-site-metas?

Tags: support, per-site-meta

I didn't see any change in rep when I got upvoted on Board and Card Games meta; how does the system work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Aside from Meta Stack Exchange (which acts as a parent site), reputation on the per-site-meta's is the same as your reputation on the parent site.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/

From the meta FAQ on SU which is similar to the others:

> What is reputation?
>
> You must have at least 5 reputation on
> the main website to participate on
> Super User Meta.
>
> Reputation here is entirely derived
> from the main website; your reputation
> is the same here as it is there,
> synchronized hourly. Votes here do not
> affect your reputation in any way.
> However, you can earn unique badges
> here on the meta site.